# javaFx gridpane

Tags: javafx, gridpane

Как получить координаты расположения элемета в gridpane по самому элементу?
Что-то вроде grid.получитьКоординатуX(объект) или как-нибудь похитрее

Answer (score 0):

Особо не тестил, но для стандартных ситуаций вроде работает:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main extends Application {
    /**
     * Все элементы одной строки имеют одинаковое свойство minY. Значит каждое уникальное значение соответсвует
     * одной строке. 
     * @param gridPane Исходная панель
     * @return Отсортированный по возрастанию массив Y координат строк. 
     */
    private static double[] getRowsY(final GridPane gridPane) {
        return gridPane.getChildren().stream()
                .mapToDouble(node -> node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY())
                .distinct().sorted().toArray();
    }

    /**
     * В рамках одной строки, каждый элемент имеет уникальное свойство minX.
     * @param gridPane Исходная панель
     * @param rowMinY Координата minY строки, для которой получаем координаты minX элементов
     * @return Отсортированный по возрастанию массив X координат элементов строки. 
     */
    private static double[] getColumnsX(final GridPane gridPane, double rowMinY) {
        return gridPane.getChildren().stream()
                .map(node -> node.getBoundsInParent())
                .filter(bounds -> bounds.getMinY() == rowMinY)
                .mapToDouble(bounds -> bounds.getMinX())
                .distinct().sorted().toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Получение координат элемента
     * @param gridPane Исходная панель
     * @param node Искомый элемент
     * @return Пара (rowIndex, columnIndex) элемента
     */
    public static Pair<Integer, Integer> getPosition(final GridPane gridPane, final Node node) {
        if (!gridPane.getChildren().contains(node)) {
            return null;
        }
        Bounds boundsInParent = node.getBoundsInParent();

        double[] rowsY = getRowsY(gridPane);
        int rowIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(rowsY, boundsInParent.getMinY());

        double[] columnsX = getColumnsX(gridPane, boundsInParent.getMinY());
        int columnIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(columnsX, boundsInParent.getMinX());

        return new Pair<>(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        final Label searched = new Label("1-2");
        final Label fail = new Label("Fail");

        gridPane.addRow(0, new Label("0-0"), new Label("0-1"), new Label("0-2"));
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Label("1-0"), new Label("1-1"), searched);
        gridPane.addRow(2, new Label("2-0"), new Label("2-1"), new Label("2-2"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane, 100, 100));
        primaryStage.show();

        System.out.println(getPosition(gridPane, fail));
        System.out.println(getPosition(gridPane, searched));
        System.out.println(getPosition(gridPane, gridPane.getChildren().get(6)));
    }

}
```